# How do I strip parenthesis from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string, like this:

```
"yellow-corn-(corn-on-the-cob)"
```

and I would like to strip the parenthesis from the string to get something like this:

```
"yellow-corn-corn-on-the-cob"
```

I believe you would use gsub to accomplish this, but I'm not sure what pattern I would need to match the parenthesis. Something like:

```
clean_string = old_string.gsub(PATTERN,"")
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
clean_string = old_string.gsub(/[()]/, "")
```

On a side note, [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is awesome to test your regular expressions quickly.

Comment: Nice, I was skeptical but then tried it and it worked. In general, do `()` not need to be escaped inside `[]`?

Comment: Typically the only characters that are not treated literally inside of `[]` character classes are ], \, ^, and -, and even then, carat and hyphen only positionally (as the first char).

Comment: I did a quick test, it looks like the only ones you have to escape (on ruby 1.9.2 at least) are [, ], / and \.

Answer (score 35):

Without regular expression:

```
"yellow-corn-(corn-on-the-cob)".delete('()') #=> "yellow-corn-corn-on-the-cob"
```

Comment: very readable, and conveniently, you dont even need to escape brackets such that `'[foo]'.delete('[]')` returns simply `'foo'` :)

Comment: +++ This is a much simpler and more apt answer than the selected one imo.